Why is there so much condemnation of Advaita and Liberation in certain Gaudiya Texts
One can find the oft quoted statement from Chaitanya Charitamrita, "listening to mayavadi(advaitic) commentary will lead to ruin" and the same preceded by "those who preach or believe in the doctrine will be punished by Yamaraja" and so on.
The point of concern is that the position and characteristics of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu are completely antagonistic to such statements, it is highly unlikely that any realised saint/avatar would resort to hurling such abuses merely for a difference in beliefs (it is another question that no primary source of what Chaitanya's philosophy actually was exists, except the ideals of extreme Bhakti).
Then we again come to Bhagvatamrita (of Sanatana) where liberation or moksha is said to be worthless because even demons can attain it. This is a huge thorn as it effectively refutes and maligns the entire Vedic and Upanishadic (Shruti) corpus as well as the views of Rishis (including Vyas himself).
What is going on here?

There's no hate. Mayavadis are criticized by the Gaudiya Vaishnava Acharyas and not the Brahmavadis who meditate on the impersonal aspect of the Absolute Truth and do not outright reject the personal aspect. All other mentions are that the happiness of kaivalya is insignificant compared to that of Bhakti or devotional service. It is a fact that demons killed by Krishna attain oneness (sometimes bhakti too like in the case of Putana).

What is the difference? There is no school of astika philosophy as far as I know which is technically Mayavadi. (I know Shankara's Advaita will be targetted but it's strictly not so). There cannot be complete gyan/end of the quest unless Brahma is realised (after that what you want to do, is the wish of the realised soul). It is going contradictory to the intuition of the Upanishads and Vedic corpus, hence the question. The biggest challenge is that Chaitanya left no work except the Shikshashtakam which has no mention of his philosophy. Everything we have comes from secondary sources.

Hearing Shankara's philosophy from the mouths of those who commit offenses unto the form of the Lord due to not having attained Brahman realization is warned against. It's possible to present Advaita without minimizing bhakti.

Actually there's one more prayer written by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu which is known as Shivashtakam.

Interestingly, I discovered that the term Mayavada or condemnation of Mayavadi is found nowhere except the Chaitanyacharitamrita. Other texts and biographies have no mention of such recitals of Chaitanya.

I think it's in the Chaitanya Bhagavata too which is another Gaudiya Vaishnava scripture. The term mayavada pre-dates Chaitanya Charitamrta by many centuries. It originates from the Padma Purana and the concept has been condemned by Ramanujaacarya, Swami Desikan (Sri Vaishnavas), Umapati Shivacharya (Shaiva from Chidambaram), etc.

You may checkout this link: https://nitaigaurangablog.wordpress.com/2021/12/18/is-the-prediction-of-shankaracarya-in-padma-purana-authentic-mayavadam-asat-shastram/

The point is that it is not seen in any other Gaudiya Text that predates Chaitanya Charitamrita, including texts by those in direct company of Chaitanya (Most importantly the Chaitanya Bhagwata, Chaitanyamangala etc.). No cross reference anywhere is a problem. As for Padma Purana reference, any verses of any Purana which highlight specific historical personalities (including Chanakya, Nanda Kings or similarly Shankaracharya) are to be seen as later interpolations (else they will raise questions on the entire Purana itself), even if they occur in many versions

I am looking at this from a non sectarian perspective. If the views of Acharyas of every sect be taken absolutely on face value (that is on matters that actually are directly attacks on the other one), we would be left in a very problematic situation. On Chaitanya Bhagwata, because Charitamrita claims that the exact term and the attacks were spoken by Chaitanya himself verbatim, we are looking for the exact or similar verses in other texts.

And why am I doing this exercise, because it has led to a bone of contention between a very friend and myself as well as rattled my own spiritual side. The statements of Chaitanya Charitamrita, A) Claim to be the exact words of Chaitanya B) Places anyone who believes in another Vedantic Philosophy at the level of an untouchable and liable to be sent to hell. In absence of any cross reference, these words are highly unlikely to come out of the mouth of any realised saint/avatar, forget someone like Chaitanya.

We can use a simple logic to rule out any reference to allegations against Shankara (or any other philosopher) in any Purana as interpolations. Assume they are not later interpolations than Shankara and also that the Puranas were composed before Shankara. Then, when Shankara did his Digvijaya and during his entire life, were all Brahmins and Acharyas of India ignorant about the major Puranas? It's ridiculous to assume so. In such case he must have met with resistance from everyone, yet he gained an unparalleled following. This alone refutes any claims of authenticity of such verses.

@SamridhJoshi Hello brother. Your logic assumes a priori that the Sankara Digvijaya of Vidyaranya (1300s), written at least 500 years after Shri Adi Sankaracharya,  is an accurate biography.  This link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara#Traditional_and_historical_views_on_Shankara) suggests that Shri Adi Sankaracharya was not well known during his lifetime and several centuries later. It could be possible that the popularity of Advaita grew slowly until the 1000s due to Puranic resistance. The historical Shri Adi Sankaracharya still remains an intriguing mystery.

He might have become a fad in several localities in different sections of Bharata during his lifetime, a fad that grew into a powerful and popular school of Vedanta several centuries later. The development of Advaita, though based on the works of Shri Sankaracharya, Shri Govindapada, and Shri Goudapada, might rest on the shoulders and hard work of people after them.

@SamridhJoshi There are other biographies of Shri Adi Sankaracharya that predate that of Vidyaranya. Examples are, but not limited to, those by Purushottama Bharati and Anandagiri. In each of these, the birth of Shri Adi Sankaracharya diverge from that found in Vidyaranya's work. The ones I cited are, interestingly, from dates in or after the 10th century, which is several centuries after the Western (700s AD) and traditional birth dates (BC era) of Shri Adi Sankaracharya

@SamridhJoshi To the remark "Then, when Shankara did his Digvijaya and during his entire life:" one cannot be sure that these happened the way devout Advaitins think they did. Why the diverging, changing, and interpolated biographies? Why not keep one and stick with it from the beginning? Why the need to change the narrative? What is going on here?

The condemnation is because adhering strictly only to Advaita and minimizing Dvaita (which is termed as Mayavada) means spiritual suicide due to sacrificing one's eternal spiritual idenitity.
Loss of identity equates to sarva-nāśa due to losing the opportunity that was given for service unto Bhagavan and His bhaktas. Hence it is said: māyāvādi-bhāṣya śunile haya sarva-nāśa.
Here's another verse from the Chaitanya Chandramrta composed by Prabhodananda Sarasvati who was previously a Tridandi Sanyasi in Sri Rangakshetra and later accepted Gaudiya Vaishnavism after meeting Lord Chaitanya personally.

kaivalyam narakāyate tridaśa-pūr ākāśa-puṣpāyate
durdāntendriya-kāla-sarpa-paṭalīm protkhāṭa-damṣṭrāyate viśvam
pūrṇa-sukhāyate vidhi-mahendrādiś ca kīṭāyate
yat-kāruṇya-kaṭākṣa-vaibhavavatām tam ga


If we look at the above verse, it may seem that the Devas all the way up to Brahma who're worshipable to humans have been condemned as tiny insects by material calculation. However this is not so because a recipient of Gauranga's mercy has become situated in His eternal position as a servant of the Lord, cannot be compared even to Indra, Brahma and other Devas which are temporary positions and no better than an illusory dream or phantasmagoria.
Below is an example from the Sankarpa Nirakaranam in Tamil (verse 254) by the Shaiva saint Umapati Shivacharya from the 13th century which also specifically condemns Mayavada.

maya vaada peya unakku devaril oruvar untaka mevarum narakam vituttalo
arite
One who has sworn by mayavada will be punished even if there is one
Deva left and all the rest are dead, and sent to Hell.”

He is said to have criticized the philosophies of Mayavada, Aikyavada, Pashanavada, Bhedavada, Shivasamavada, Isvara ayikiyavada, Nimitta Karana parinamavada, and Shaivavada in his work.
The realization that the divine form of the Lord is superior to impersonal liberation is also accepted by Satyavrata Muni during a conversation with Sri Narada and Saunaka.

varam deva moksham na mokshavadhim va na canyam vrine ’ham vareshad
apiha idam te vapur natha gopala-balam sada me manasy avirastam kim
anyaih
O Lord, although You are able to give all kinds of benedictions, I do
not pray to You for the boon of impersonal liberation, nor the highest
liberation of eternal life in Vaikuntha, nor any other boon [which may
be obtained by executing the nine processes of bhakti]. O Lord, I
simply wish that this form of Yours as Bala Gopala in Vrindavana may
ever be manifest in my heart, for what is the use to me of any other
boon besides this? (Damodarashtakam verse 4).

As per the Bhagavata Purana, Sri Vedavyasa himself was dissatisfied even after compiling the Vedas, Mahabharata, and other shastras with perfect logic as He did not glorify the personality of Godhead.

श्रीनारद उवाच भवतानुदितप्रायं यशो भगवतोऽमलम् । येनैवासौ न तुष्येत
मन्ये तद्दर्शनं खिलम् ॥ ८ ॥
Śrī Nārada said: You have not actually broadcast the sublime and
spotless glories of the Personality of Godhead. That philosophy which
does not satisfy the transcendental senses of the Lord is considered
worthless.
न यद्वचश्चित्रपदं हरेर्यशो जगत्पवित्रं प्रगृणीत कर्हिचित् । तद्वायसं
तीर्थमुशन्ति मानसा न यत्र हंसा निरमन्त्युशिक्क्षया: ॥ १० ॥
Those words which do not describe the glories of the Lord, who alone
can sanctify the atmosphere of the whole universe, are considered by
saintly persons to be like unto a place of pilgrimage for crows. Since
the all-perfect persons are inhabitants of the transcendental abode,
they do not derive any pleasure there.
तद्वाग्विसर्गो जनताघविप्लवो यस्मिन् प्रतिश्लोकमबद्धवत्यपि ।
नामान्यनन्तस्य यशोऽङ्कितानि यत् श‍ृण्वन्ति गायन्ति गृणन्ति साधव: ॥ ११
॥
On the other hand, that literature which is full of descriptions of
the transcendental glories of the name, fame, forms, pastimes, etc.,
of the unlimited Supreme Lord is a different creation, full of
transcendental words directed toward bringing about a revolution in
the impious lives of this world’s misdirected civilization. Such
transcendental literatures, even though imperfectly composed, are
heard, sung and accepted by purified men who are thoroughly honest.
tato ’nyathā kiñcana yad vivakṣataḥ pṛthag dṛśas
tat-kṛta-rūpa-nāmabhiḥ na karhicit kvāpi ca duḥsthitā matir labheta
vātāhata-naur ivāspadam
Whatever you desire to describe that is separate in vision from the
Lord simply reacts, with different forms, names and results, to
agitate the mind, as the wind agitates a boat which has no resting
place.

So condemnation of Mayavada where the Bheda aspect of Parabrahman (which is Achintya Bheda-Abheda) is minimized, is not uncommon. It's just that we have easier access to Gaudiya literature over other texts.

Now, Chaitanya Bhagwata, which happens to be the first biography of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu has no mention of any debate with Sarvabhauma, atleast the kind of depicted in Charitamrita. The episode narrated in the Bhagwata only mentions Sarvabhauma questioning the sanyasa of Chaitanya, Chaitanya explaining to him the meaning of atmaram verse and then showing his six armed form. Also, Krishnadas Kaviraj gave a second hand account of what he heard or read from other accounts and CC is not a first hand account. (Although, Kaviraj did definitely write everything with right intentions as per his Bhava)

I can fully agree and appreciate the fact that a Bhakta/Acharya in devotional mode rejects any other thing than seva to his chosen lord. Infact that is the pinnacle of the practice of Bhakti. The question and objection is "Were these the words of Chaitanya or attributed to him by Krishnadas Kaviraj". The question arises because attribution is very common in biographies and also that no other biography of Chaitanya mentions it. There is another debate also raging on the Madhava Sampradaya connection of Chaitanya which occurs in very late texts and absent in all earlier biographies.

A) Of course not, there's no question of untouchability or sending anyone to hell resulting from anger or envy. B) Krishnadas Kaviraj humbly presented the Chaitanya Charitamrta based on the Sanskrit notes (karca) of Svarupa Damodar.

Though I am an insignificant living being, through the blessings of Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu I have summarized in writing everything that Svarupa Damodar recorded in his notes about the Lord’s pastimes, as well as everything that I heard from the mouth of Raghunath Das. (Chaitanya Charitamrita 3.3.269-70)

On the basis of Krishnadas Kaviraj and Raghunath das Goswami's saintly character, I am willing to vouch for the authenticity of the Chaitanya Charitamrta.
